# File uploading in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I simply tried this, but its not working, what is the problem in it,

MY index page:

```
 @{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

  @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/from-    data" }))
    { 
       <div>
       <h1 style="align-content: center; color: blueviolet">Application to upload files</h1>
       </div>
       <div>
       <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
       <br />
       <input type="submit" id="load" name="submit" value="Submit" />
       </div>

       }
```

And My controller is,

```
                  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        string path = @"~/Content/Upload";

        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["file"];

        if (file != null)
            file.SaveAs(path + file.FileName);

        return Content("Sucess");
    }
```

Comment: "It's not working".  What isn't working?  What error are you getting?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your code?

Comment: `"mulitipart/from-    data"` doesn't look quite right. Try `"multipart/form-data"`

Comment: i tried "multipart/from-data" isn't worked, actually the error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object, when i upload the file, and pass the value to controller, file value is null in controller.

Comment: **form**, not **from**

Comment: @Mahendra Please pay attention to the detail of the `enctype` value that commenters are trying to point out, and it would also be helpful if you could include information about *what exactly* is not working.

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake, sorry for the inconvenience. now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you are attempting to save your file to looks wrong. Try with MapPath:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload");
    if (file != null)
    {
        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, file.FileName));
    }

    return Content("Sucess");
}
```

Also make sure that you have used the correct `enctype` attribute in your form:

```
enctype = "multipart/form-data"
```

instead of:

```
enctype = "multipart/from-    data"
```